# How high read, (very) high write databases are handled?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, system-design

I was recently going through some system design videos and stumbled upon youtube system design. And some of the specs mentioned in the video made me wonder how youtube handles all the comments on its platform. There must be billions of entries daily in the "comments" table.

1. Is all that stored in a single table? Is a table with trillions of entries maintainable?
2. How does fetching comments for a particular video works? Shouldn't the latency be super high considering the data to look through?
3. If there is some indexing based on, say video_id, would the index be maintainable?
4. 10 year old videos can have 10 year old comments as well as 1 day old comments. So, does partitioning play any kind of role here?
5. Another important thing would be comment threads. How are those maintained?

I tried googling the stuff but could not find anything relevant. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would recommend to look into https://github.com/donnemartin/system-design-primer as a good starting point for system design.

As for your particular questions, there is no single right answer, but here is one of approaches:

1. Is all that stored in a single table? Is a table with trillions of entries maintainable?

Table is a logical construct. Under the hood, the engine would do all required replication and partitioning. So even if from an application point of view it is a single table, the data itself is distributed.

2. How does fetching comments for a particular video works? Shouldn't the latency be super high considering the data to look through?

Systems tend to treat differently more and less popular resources. For less popular one, it is ok to have a higher latency, this is a reasonable trade off. For more popular resources two approaches are widely used: a) caching and b) storing related data next to each other (e.g. store all or part of comments in a single logical record for a single read).

These data systems are typically NoSQL, which means they are optimized by design for specific use cases. See a tutorial for such design here: https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cassandra/data_modeling/index.html I recommend to read the whole section, noting a different approach between sql and nosql.

3. If there is some indexing based on, say video_id, would the index be maintainable?

Index can be treated as any other data, e.g. being distributed.

4. 10 year old videos can have 10 year old comments as well as 1 day old comments. So, does partitioning play any kind of role here?

As mentioned above, comments may be stored a a single entity, or bundled together on read&cache operation. Heavily depends on details of implementation and tradeoffs.

5. Another important thing would be comment threads. How are those maintained?

I would keep top level comments in a single data structure (same record in a database) for easy retrieval. And I would keep each thread separately and reading those on demand.